# Google Cloud Speech-to-text very inaccurate, last result contains all others and speakerTag only on last result

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm using google speech-to-text using the command line and getting weird results

this is my command

```
gcloud beta ml speech recognize-long-running gs://my_bucket_name/call0.mp3 
--language-code=en-US --async --include-word-time-offsets --enable-speaker-diarization 
--diarization-speaker-count=2
```

This is the audio file:
https://dcs.megaphone.fm/LIT9020259030.mp3?key=4b567156fd7bdfaa90992664d4bc667c

The problems are:

1. the results is very very bad and inaccurate
2. the last result contains all the other results combined
3. the speakerTag only presents in the last result
4. I got the speakerTag only for speaker 1

Here's the result json:

```
{
  "done": true,
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata",
    "lastUpdateTime": "2020-07-13T18:56:33.689140Z",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2020-07-13T18:27:45.757871Z",
    "uri": "gs://deepagent-db032.appspot.com/conmagi/call1.mp3"
  },
  "name": "398565854464473919",
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
    "results": [
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.87135065,
            "transcript": "love",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "11.300s",
                "startTime": "10.400s",
                "word": "love"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.48216835,
            "transcript": "you are",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "425.100s",
                "startTime": "424.500s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "425.400s",
                "startTime": "425.100s",
                "word": "are"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.9194219,
            "transcript": "how far is it from",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "475.200s",
                "startTime": "473.800s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.500s",
                "startTime": "475.200s",
                "word": "far"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.700s",
                "startTime": "475.500s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.800s",
                "startTime": "475.700s",
                "word": "it"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "476.100s",
                "startTime": "475.800s",
                "word": "from"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.823343,
            "transcript": "I want",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "629.200s",
                "startTime": "626.700s",
                "word": "I"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "629.800s",
                "startTime": "629.200s",
                "word": "want"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.56559134,
            "transcript": "Blue Ivy",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "990.100s",
                "startTime": "989.500s",
                "word": "Blue"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "991.100s",
                "startTime": "990.100s",
                "word": "Ivy"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.78465956,
            "transcript": "how old is Wawa",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "1599.700s",
                "startTime": "1598.500s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.100s",
                "startTime": "1599.700s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.200s",
                "startTime": "1600.100s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.600s",
                "startTime": "1600.200s",
                "word": "Wawa"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.9475956,
            "transcript": "how are you",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "2022.400s",
                "startTime": "2020s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2022.500s",
                "startTime": "2022.400s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2022.600s",
                "startTime": "2022.500s",
                "word": "you"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.7494768,
            "transcript": "New York mall",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "2066.200s",
                "startTime": "2065.800s",
                "word": "New"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2066.500s",
                "startTime": "2066.200s",
                "word": "York"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2067s",
                "startTime": "2066.500s",
                "word": "mall"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.6706576,
            "transcript": "call",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "2255.600s",
                "startTime": "2254.500s",
                "word": "call"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.87819797,
            "transcript": "call Paul Wall",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "3041.500s",
                "startTime": "3040.300s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3041.800s",
                "startTime": "3041.500s",
                "word": "Paul"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3042.300s",
                "startTime": "3041.800s",
                "word": "Wall"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.8331511,
            "transcript": "no",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "3101.300s",
                "startTime": "3100.800s",
                "word": "no"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.62488914,
            "transcript": "call Jeff",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "3473.100s",
                "startTime": "3470.300s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3473.500s",
                "startTime": "3473.100s",
                "word": "Jeff"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.9074697,
            "transcript": "call home",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "4166.100s",
                "startTime": "4162.400s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4166.400s",
                "startTime": "4166.100s",
                "word": "home"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.7917781,
            "transcript": "how old are you",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "4231.800s",
                "startTime": "4231.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.200s",
                "startTime": "4231.800s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.300s",
                "startTime": "4232.200s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.400s",
                "startTime": "4232.300s",
                "word": "you"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.70297575,
            "transcript": " Europe",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "4244.200s",
                "startTime": "4243s",
                "word": "Europe"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.84273374,
            "transcript": " how are you",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "5121.500s",
                "startTime": "5115.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "5122.100s",
                "startTime": "5121.500s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "5122.300s",
                "startTime": "5122.100s",
                "word": "you"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.7561751,
            "transcript": " the only one",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "6199.900s",
                "startTime": "6199.600s",
                "word": "the"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6200.400s",
                "startTime": "6199.900s",
                "word": "only"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6200.800s",
                "startTime": "6200.400s",
                "word": "one"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.6547922,
            "transcript": " call",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "6258.800s",
                "startTime": "6256.800s",
                "word": "call"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.9402823,
            "transcript": " Walgreens",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "6925s",
                "startTime": "6912.300s",
                "word": "Walgreens"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.5217668,
            "transcript": " we want to watch",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "7155.900s",
                "startTime": "7155.500s",
                "word": "we"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.500s",
                "startTime": "7155.900s",
                "word": "want"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.600s",
                "startTime": "7156.500s",
                "word": "to"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.700s",
                "startTime": "7156.600s",
                "word": "watch"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.7971729,
            "transcript": " I love you",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "7199.900s",
                "startTime": "7199.200s",
                "word": "I"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7202.900s",
                "startTime": "7199.900s",
                "word": "love"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7203.100s",
                "startTime": "7202.900s",
                "word": "you"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "confidence": 0.8566783,
            "transcript": " how old is Moana",
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "7483.800s",
                "startTime": "7481.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484s",
                "startTime": "7483.800s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484.200s",
                "startTime": "7484s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484.300s",
                "startTime": "7484.200s",
                "word": "Moana"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "languageCode": "en-us"
      },
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "words": [
              {
                "endTime": "11.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "10.400s",
                "word": "love"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "425.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "424.500s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "425.400s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "425.100s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "473.800s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "475.200s",
                "word": "far"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.700s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "475.500s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "475.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "475.700s",
                "word": "it"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "476.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "475.800s",
                "word": "from"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "629.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "626.700s",
                "word": "I"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "629.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "629.200s",
                "word": "want"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "990.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "989.500s",
                "word": "Blue"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "991.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "990.100s",
                "word": "Ivy"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1599.700s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "1598.500s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "1599.700s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "1600.100s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "1600.600s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "1600.200s",
                "word": "Wawa"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2022.400s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2020s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2022.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2022.400s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2022.600s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2022.500s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2066.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2065.800s",
                "word": "New"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2066.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2066.200s",
                "word": "York"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2067s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2066.500s",
                "word": "mall"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "2255.600s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "2254.500s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3041.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3040.300s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3041.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3041.500s",
                "word": "Paul"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3042.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3041.800s",
                "word": "Wall"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3101.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3100.800s",
                "word": "no"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3473.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3470.300s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "3473.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "3473.100s",
                "word": "Jeff"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4166.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4162.400s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4166.400s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4166.100s",
                "word": "home"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4231.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4231.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4231.800s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4232.200s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4232.400s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4232.300s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "4244.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "4243s",
                "word": "Europe"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "5121.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "5115.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "5122.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "5121.500s",
                "word": "are"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "5122.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "5122.100s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6199.900s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "6199.600s",
                "word": "the"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6200.400s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "6199.900s",
                "word": "only"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6200.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "6200.400s",
                "word": "one"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6258.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "6256.800s",
                "word": "call"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "6925s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "6912.300s",
                "word": "Walgreens"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7155.900s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7155.500s",
                "word": "we"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.500s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7155.900s",
                "word": "want"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.600s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7156.500s",
                "word": "to"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7156.700s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7156.600s",
                "word": "watch"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7199.900s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7199.200s",
                "word": "I"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7202.900s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7199.900s",
                "word": "love"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7203.100s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7202.900s",
                "word": "you"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7483.800s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7481.300s",
                "word": "how"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7483.800s",
                "word": "old"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484.200s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7484s",
                "word": "is"
              },
              {
                "endTime": "7484.300s",
                "speakerTag": 1,
                "startTime": "7484.200s",
                "word": "Moana"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you raise an issue about this anywhere in [Google's GitHub repo](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech)? Asking as I'm experiencing the same problem, tks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issues, specially related to diarization where there is not a good performance.
I have tried to get my script from AWS as well, but I found the word error rate was higher, but it is better recognizing transition from person to person.

As you are aware, this is a beta feature and being in that stage they don't have a SLA (Service Level Agreement) to accomplish.
I reported this bug to the Google Team, and they have replied:

> There are no SLAs or technical support obligations in a beta release
> unless otherwise specified in product terms[...]. The average beta
> phase lasts about six months.

So I believe it will take a while for the team to officially release this feature.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices

Answer (score 0):

Speaker Tag, is deprecated in this API, and speakerTag will hardly give the accurate results, I would suggest you to use ChannelTag in place of SpeakerTag like result.channelTag, you might get better results.

Comment: I don't have separated channels in my audio files

Comment: if there are no separated channels result.ChannelTag will return atleast 1 and therefor you will get one channelTag for all the words and if there are multiple channles than you have enable speaker diariazation for it which can seperate channels and than by channeltag you can see which channel word it is

Comment: ok thanks, but I need the speaker diarization feature for the same channel

Comment: @AvielNiego you can enable speaker diarization in recognization config or diarization config and can use channelTag instead of speakerTag as speakerTag is deprecated and not accurate most of the times, as you don't have separated channels you will not see the difference but if there are multiple channel you can actually get the channel which is speaking by using channelTag in your word, start time and end time iterating loop...